# WordPress API media query returning all file types except jpeg

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to get a list of media that matches a certain filename using the WordPress REST API v2.  If I'm searching for pdfs or pngs, it seems to work correctly, but I can't get it to return any JPEG images using the media query.  I've  tried it using the Python wordpress-api package and also tried it directly in a browser.  My query URL looks like this:

https://oururl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=filename.jpg

when I do a query without the search, it returns the 10 most recent pdf and png files uploaded, but skips any jpegs that were uploaded.  since our site uses mostly jpeg images, this isn't going to work for us.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: I think i may have figured out why the jpegs aren't showing up, however I'm not certain how to fix the problem.  On our site, all of the jpegs, are attached to posts. Some of the posts are private, and some are public.  I could understand a little more if the public ones showed up, but not the private, but any attached images don't show up. Looks like the problem, then, is that it's not returning any attached media.

Comment: Alright, figured something else out.  Most of our posts are 'Custom Post Types'.  When we use standard wordpress post types (posts, pages, etc), it works, but with custom post types, it doesn't.  does the API just not support custom post types?